# Manual login does not work if an email is sent in the same action

Tags: symfony, security-context-token

In our project, the signup process automatically logs in the user after registration like this:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, $firewallName, $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

Which works just fine **unless** we also send an email in the same action.

For emails we are using swiftmailer.

Can anyone shed some light on this? Why does this happen? What can I do to keep the user logged, and also send the email?

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: The question is twofold: Why does this happen? And, how can I have the cake and eat it too? (fire the event AND keep the user logged in)

Comment: This is, for sure, a SYmfony2 "Because Yes"... Because? Why yes!

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out.

This only happens when you have spooling enabled in swiftmailer. Once spooling is disabled, everything works as expected.

Now, why spooling breaks this is beyond me, I'll keep on digging.